# Yebum, the man wants it but the woman doesn't

Tags: yibbum-chalitza-levirate

Let's say, Chas V'Shalom, a man died childless, leaving his wife a Yivamah. He has a brother, who by Torah law must either marry his diseased brother's wife, or perform Chalitzah.

What if he wants to marry her but she doesn't want to marry him. Do they have to perform Chalitzah, or are they Halachicly married?

Comment: you can't be married to someone that doesn't agree to be married to you

Comment: @dude in this case that's not true

Comment: M.Broder, they're not Halakhically married until they do Yibbum. Just "wanting" doesn't effect anything.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45195/759